# Form Element Appended from Ajax not working-

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core

I have this code for form method in ajax

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/MainPage/GetAllRecords",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            
            $("#loadNotes").append(
                '<form method="GET">' +
                '<div class="container py-3 px-4" style = "background-color: #fff;position:relative; height: 8rem; border: #80808012 solid 1px; /* margin-top: 1rem; */ box-shadow: blue; margin-bottom: 7px; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;  /* overflow-wrap: break-word; */ ">' +

                '<a class="stretched-link" asp-controller="MainPage" asp-action="ShowRecord" asp-route-id="' + value.id + '"style = "color: #6d1cccbf; font-weight: 500; text-decoration:underline;" type="submit">' + value.title + '</a>' +
                '<p style="color: #5b5454;font-size: 11pt;height: 3rem; white-space:unset" class="text-break text-truncate">' + value.description + '</p>' +

                '</div>' +
                '</form>'
               ) ;
        });
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

**I already tried** to put the form method and other elements **under cshtml file** and from there **it works**, it is calling the controller and view **but not from ajax.**

what am I missing? Please help thank you

Comment: Hi @devdeb26, what did your view display from ajax now? Does the `Console` panel(F12 in browser) appear any error message? Could you please share your response data? Also, share your backend code.

Comment: Besides, Tag Helpers are interpreted. In other words, Razor must see them as actual tags in order to replace them. Here, it's just a JS string, and Razor will not mess with that. So it will not generate the href by js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a whole working demo:

Model:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
<div id=loadNotes>

</div>
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/MainPage/GetAllRecords",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            
                        $("#loadNotes").append(
                            '<form method="GET">' +
                            '<div class="container py-3 px-4" style = "background-color: #fff;position:relative; height: 8rem; border: #80808012 solid 1px; /* margin-top: 1rem; */ box-shadow: blue; margin-bottom: 7px; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;  /* overflow-wrap: break-word; */ ">' +
                //change here.......    
                            '<a class="stretched-link" href="/MainPage/ShowRecord/' + value.id + '"style = "color: #6d1cccbf; font-weight: 500; text-decoration:underline;" type="submit">' + value.title + '</a>' +
                            '<p style="color: #5b5454;font-size: 11pt;height: 3rem; white-space:unset" class="text-break text-truncate">' + value.description + '</p>' +

                            '</div>' +
                            '</form>'
                            ) ;
                    });
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                }
            });
        })
         
    </script>
}
```

Controller:

```
public class MainPageController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult GetAllRecords()
    {
        //hard-coded the data for easy testing
        var model = new List<TestModel>()
        {
            new TestModel(){Id=1,Title="aa",Description="des1"},
            new TestModel(){Id=2,Title="bb",Description="des2"},
            new TestModel(){Id=3,Title="cc",Description="des3"}
        };
        return Json(model);
    }
}
```

### Note:

Tag Helpers are interpreted. In other words, Razor must see them as actual tags in order to replace them. Here, it's just a JS string, and Razor will not mess with that. So it will not generate the href by js.

You need to set the href value manually. Change the js to:

```
'<a class="stretched-link" href="/MainPage/ShowRecord/' + value.id + '"style = "color: #6d1cccbf; font-weight: 500; text-decoration:underline;" type="submit">' + value.title + '</a>' +
```

Comment: Thank you! this works! Thank you so much for the explanation. I know now why my taghelpers are not working on the ajax ! Bless you

Answer (score 0):

the **type** property you passed as GET should be method I suppose.

The remaining code seems ok. Have you checked your browser console for errors ?

Comment: there's no console errors in the dev tools, no errors as well on my local solution :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe store the html "form tag" in a variable first then use .html() to append the forms to #loadNotes

And make sure add (document) after your '#loadNotes' to absolutely find the element in the document. $("#loadNotes", `document`)

Also success: function and error: function is kinda old. try .done and .fail

Old Method of Ajax.

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/MainPage/GetAllRecords",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        var html_forms = '';
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                html_forms += '<form method="GET">' +
                '<div class="container py-3 px-4" style = "background-color: #fff;position:relative; height: 8rem; border: #80808012 solid 1px; /* margin-top: 1rem; */ box-shadow: blue; margin-bottom: 7px; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;  /* overflow-wrap: break-word; */ ">' +
                '<a class="stretched-link" asp-controller="MainPage" asp-action="ShowRecord" asp-route-id="' + value.id + '"style = "color: #6d1cccbf; font-weight: 500; text-decoration:underline;" type="submit">' + value.title + '</a>' +
                '<p style="color: #5b5454;font-size: 11pt;height: 3rem; white-space:unset" class="text-break text-truncate">' + value.description + '</p>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</form>';
        });

        $("#loadNotes", document).html(html_forms);
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

New Method of Ajax

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/MainPage/GetAllRecords",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
}).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var html_forms = '';
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                html_forms += '<form method="GET">' +
                '<div class="container py-3 px-4" style = "background-color: #fff;position:relative; height: 8rem; border: #80808012 solid 1px; /* margin-top: 1rem; */ box-shadow: blue; margin-bottom: 7px; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;  /* overflow-wrap: break-word; */ ">' +
                '<a class="stretched-link" asp-controller="MainPage" asp-action="ShowRecord" asp-route-id="' + value.id + '"style = "color: #6d1cccbf; font-weight: 500; text-decoration:underline;" type="submit">' + value.title + '</a>' +
                '<p style="color: #5b5454;font-size: 11pt;height: 3rem; white-space:unset" class="text-break text-truncate">' + value.description + '</p>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</form>';
        });

        $("#loadNotes", document).html(html_forms);
}).fail(function(response) {
       alert(response);
});
```

EDIT: Change this part to `< button`

From this

```
'<a class="stretched-link" asp-controller="MainPage" asp-action="ShowRecord" asp-route-id="' + value.id + '"style = "color: #6d1cccbf; font-weight: 500; text-decoration:underline;" type="submit">' + value.title + '</a>'
```

To this

```
'<button class="stretched-link" asp-controller="MainPage" asp-action="ShowRecord" asp-route-id="' + value.id + '"style = "color: #6d1cccbf; font-weight: 500; text-decoration:underline;" type="submit">' + value.title + '</button>'
```

and add action on this

```
html_forms += '<form action="php_controller.php" method="GET">' +
```

Comment: yes i updated my old ajax to new one and it still did append my html forms, unfortunately, whenever i click on the link it didn't call the controller and action. In short, it didn't do anything after i click it. :(

Comment: @devdeb26 check my edit.

Comment: Hi thank you! This doesn't work but it help me in knowing there's already a new format for ajax which I will always use from now on. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

use Backtick ``

```
$("#loadNotes").append(`
    <form method="GET">
        <div class="container py-3 px-4" style = "background-color: #fff;position:relative; height: 8rem; border: #80808012 solid 1px; box-shadow: blue; margin-bottom: 7px; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; ">
           <a class="stretched-link" asp-controller="MainPage" asp-action="ShowRecord" asp-route-id="` + value.id + `"style = "color: #6d1cccbf; font-weight: 500; text-decoration:underline;" type="submit"> ` + value.title + `</a>
           <p style="color: #5b5454;font-size: 11pt;height: 3rem; white-space:unset" class="text-break text-truncate">` + value.description + `</p>
        </div>
    </form>
`);
```

Comment: Use backtick ``

Comment: Hi I just tried your suggestion, but still not lead me to the controller view. I do not have console errors as well on the dev tools same as in my local

Comment: @devdeb26 check my edit.